# java use httpClient to access http server url(need authentication) through proxy(need authentication)

Tags: java, http

Client ----->proxy(need authentication)----->target_server(need authentication)

I use apache's HttpClient to be the client.At present,I have no idea how to pass the authentication on target_server.

```
 import com.sun.deploy.net.HttpResponse;

public class Test {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = null;
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope("[target-url-domain]"), AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("usrename", "password"));
    credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope("[proxy-domain]"), AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("usrename", "password"));

    SSLcontextBuilder builder = new SSLCOntextBuilder();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(builder.build);

    httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();

    String url = "targetUrl";
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(new HttpHost("[proxyUrl]", 89)).build();
    httpGet.setConfig(config);
    HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
}
```

}

it returns connection reset error.

Comment: Well, perhaps you should add a bit more code into the question, and possibly, what kind of authentication are you using, etc.

Comment: And so far you've tried?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I have put the code.

Comment: @lexicore yeap, from now, when i combined the two authentication, it will show connection reset errors.